# How to connect correctly to the database?

Tags: error-handling

I am not sure why I would have an error when trying to connect to odbc

proc sql;
    24   create table xxx.test as
    25   (select * from nxxxe.nxrxxt);

1) the connection is successful
2) libref successful

I did not execute any queries. How come I have a syntax error? I even did not have any `)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You do have parentheses in your query; try removing them:

```
proc sql;
create table kyle.test as
select * 
from noagree.no_agreement_list;
quit;
```

But try this with a small table to begin with.  Also, especially with Teradata, it's very important that you specify the index.  Using the code you have, the first SAS variable in the data set will be used as the index.  A poorly chosen index can have seriously negative consequences on your database (affecting other users as well as yourself.

I use SAS/Access to Teradata myself so I don't know if these options are available with ODBC, but here is an example of how to explicitly define the index and various column types:

```
data kyle.test
     ( dbcreate_table_opts='primary index(INDEX_COLUMN)'
       dbtype=( INDEX_COLUMN='INTEGER NOT NULL'
              , USER_NAME='VARCHAR(120) CHARACTER SET LATIN NOT CASESPECIFIC'
              , PHONE_NUMBER='CHAR(10)'
              , CONTACT_DATE="DATE FORMAT 'yyyy-mm-dd'"
              , FROM_LINE_NUM='SMALLINT'
              , DOLLAR_DATA='DECIMAL(15,2)'
              )
      );
   set noagree.no_agreement_list;
run;
```

Note this uses a normal SAS data step rather than `PROC SQL`; any variable in the data set that is not listed in the `dbtype` option will be copied using the standard SAS conversion.

Finally, once you get this to work, be sure to run a 'collect statistics' step, which you can do using the SQL Assistant tool (SQLA). I assume you have access to SQLA, especially if you have write permission to some database.